# get data from key-vair pair from object of array based on condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object that some object with key-value pair for `label`, `value` and some do not. I want to get the new array that the object with both label, value and code key-value pair
The way I did is using a map and then filter out. if there is a better way to do it? I feel like I just iterate the same array twice and it is not efficient?

```
  const datas = [
    {label:'a', value:'a', code:'a'},
    {label:'b', value:'b', code:'b'},
    {value:'b', code:'b'},
    {label:'c', code:'c'},
    {code:'d'},
  ]
  const b = datas.map((n) => {return (n?.label && n?.value) && n} ).filter((n)=>n !==undefined)

  expect(b).to.deep.equal([{label:'a', value:'a', code:'a'}, {label:'b', value:'b', code:'b'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.map` is superfluous. Just filter by whether the `label` and `value` properties both exist:

```js
const datas = [
    {label:'a', value:'a', code:'a'},
    {label:'b', value:'b', code:'b'},
    {value:'b', code:'b'},
    {label:'c', code:'c'},
    {code:'d'},
]
const b = datas.filter(n => n?.label && n?.value);
console.log(b);
```

If the array items always exist, as they do in the example in the question, you can remove the optional chains too, and just use `n.label && n.value`.